# Configure DeadLetter queue for send endpoint

Tags: masstransit

I am trying to configure a Producer to send a message to a Consumer that has a deadletter queue configured. The Producer is using a SendEndpoint (Or rather the request/response pattern), but I get an exception from RabbitMQ.

I have the following consumer:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddConsumer<SomeMessageRequestConsumer>();

        x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(busConfig =>
        {
            busConfig.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://rabbit@localhost"), "/", hostConfigurator =>
            {
                hostConfigurator.Password("Guest");
                hostConfigurator.Username("Guest");
            });

            busConfig.ReceiveEndpoint(nameof(SomeMessage), x =>
            {
                x.ConfigureConsumer<SomeMessageRequestConsumer>(provider);
                x.Durable = false;
                x.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;

                x.BindDeadLetterQueue("SomeMessageDeadLetter", "SomeMessageDeadLetter", null);
             });
          }));
       });

    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
}
```

I have the following Producer:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSingleton<IReplyToClientFactory, ReplyToClientFactory>();

    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(busConfig =>
        {
            busConfig.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://rabbit@localhost"), "/", hostConfigurator =>
            {
                hostConfigurator.Password("Guest");
                hostConfigurator.Username("Guest");
            });
        }));
    });

    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
}
```

In the Producer project I have a controller that send the message like so:

```
    public ProducerController(IReplyToClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var serviceAddress = new Uri($"queue:{nameof(SomeMessage)}?durable=false");
        var client = this.clientFactory.GetFactory().CreateRequestClient<SomeMessage>(serviceAddress);

        var (successResponse, failResponse) = await client.GetResponse<SomeMessageSuccessResponse, SomeMessageFailResponse>(new SomeMessage()
        {
            Text = "Hello",
        }, cancellationToken, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        return Ok();
    }
```

I get the following error on RabbitMQ :

```
operation queue.declare caused a channel exception precondition_failed: inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'SomeMessage' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'SomeMessageDeadLetter' of type 'longstr'
```

I have tried to configure the deadletter on the Publish, Send and Message Topologies but with no success. Is what I am trying to do possible or am I chasing the wind here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the destination address from a queue to an exchange, to decouple your producer from the consumer queue configuration. To send to the exchange, changed your address format to:

`$"exchange:{nameof(SomeMessage)}"`

That way, you don't need to know the queue configuration to send the request.